# I get a syntax error when I try to run this

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try to run this, I get a syntax error and it doesn't say what line it is or anything. I don't know what else I could say.. Here's the bit of code that gets the error:

```
if "q" in attack:
        if random.randint(1,100) != range(1,21):
            print("You hit with a quick attack!")
            ehp -= 20
            print("The",enam,"loses 20 damage! It now has",ehp,"health.")
        else:
            print("You missed.. :(")
    elif "p" in attack:
        if random.randint(1,100) != range(1,51):
            print("You hit with a power attack!")
            ehp -= 50
            print("The",enam,"loses 50 damage! It now has",ehp,"health.")
        else:
            print("You missed.. :(")
    elif "1" in attack:
        if mana >= skill1[2]:
            print("You hit with",skill1[0])
            ehp -= skill1[1]
            mana -= skill1[2]
            print("The",enam,"loses",skill1[1],"damage! It now has",ehp,"health.")
            print("You now have",mana,"mana.")
    elif "2" in attack:
        if mana >= skill2[2]:
            print("You hit with",skill2[0])
            ehp -= skill2[1]
            mana -= skill2[2]
            print("The",enam,"loses",skill2[1],"damage! It now has",ehp,"health.")
            print("You now have",mana,"mana.")
    elif "3" in attack:
        if mana >= skill3[2]:
            print("You hit with",skill3[0])
            ehp -= skill3[1]
            mana -= skill3[2]
            print("The",enam,"loses",skill3[1],"damage! It now has",ehp,"health.")
            print("You now have",mana,"mana.")
    else:
        print("You typed something wrong.")
```

By the way, skill1, skill2 and skill3 are all lists for the different skills in the game i'm making, skill1[0] is the name of the skill, skill[1] is the skills' attack power and skill[2] is the mana used to use a skill.

```
skill1 = []
skill2 = []
skill3 = []

skill1.append("Very Weak Fireball")
skill1.append(20)
skill1.append(30)
skill2.append("Weak Fireball")
skill2.append(30)
skill2.append(40)
skill3.append("Average Fireball")
skill3.append(40)
skill3.append(50)
```

Comment: Which syntax error? It usually gives you the line number that's wrong, which would be incredibly useful here. But since you say it doesn't, the exact error does get all the more interesting

Comment: Make sure you correctly indented your code (first `if` statement)

Comment: Please watch your indentations..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest the elif inside the if:

```
if "q" in attack: # in line with the elif's
    if random.randint(1,100) > 21: # cannot compare to range use > 
        print("You hit with a quick attack!")
        ehp -= 20
        print("The",enam,"loses 20 damage! It now has",ehp,"health.")
    else:
        print("You missed.. :(")
elif "p" in attack:
    if random.randint(1,100)> 51: # greater that 51
        print("You hit with a power attack!")
        ehp -= 50
        print("The",enam,"loses 50 damage! It now has",ehp,"health.")
    else:
        print("You missed.. :(")
elif "1" in attack:
```

The rest of your code syntax is fine, just change range to `>` .

Answer (score 0):

There's so much problematical about your code. For example:

```
    if random.randint(1,100) != range(1,21):
```

what you're doing here is comparing an integer (the random number between 1 and 100) with a list (the output of range, which is `[1,2, ..., 20`). What you've meant is probably `not (... in range(...))`; which is OK, but the most time and memory consuming method of checking if a number is between two other numbers. However, that is not a Syntax error.

However the point here is that you don't indent properly; your `elif`s must have the same indent depth as the corresponding `if`s.

Answer (score 0):

As the output of IDLE for me :

> unindent does not match any outer indentation level

You didn't used indentations correct.

check the below :

```
if "q" in attack:
    if random.randint(1,100) != range(1,21):
        print("You hit with a quick attack!")
        ehp -= 20
        print("The",enam,"loses 20 damage! It now has",ehp,"health.")
    else:
        print("You missed.. :(")
elif "p" in attack:
    if random.randint(1,100) != range(1,51):
        print("You hit with a power attack!")
        ehp -= 50
        print("The",enam,"loses 50 damage! It now has",ehp,"health.")
    else:
        print("You missed.. :(")
elif "1" in attack:
    if mana >= skill1[2]:
        print("You hit with",skill1[0])
        ehp -= skill1[1]
        mana -= skill1[2]
        print("The",enam,"loses",skill1[1],"damage! It now has",ehp,"health.")
        print("You now have",mana,"mana.")
elif "2" in attack:
    if mana >= skill2[2]:
        print("You hit with",skill2[0])
        ehp -= skill2[1]
        mana -= skill2[2]
        print("The",enam,"loses",skill2[1],"damage! It now has",ehp,"health.")
        print("You now have",mana,"mana.")
elif "3" in attack:
    if mana >= skill3[2]:
        print("You hit with",skill3[0])
        ehp -= skill3[1]
        mana -= skill3[2]
        print("The",enam,"loses",skill3[1],"damage! It now has",ehp,"health.")
        print("You now have",mana,"mana.")
    else:
        print("You typed something wrong.")
```

after that if you didn't define *attack*, you will receive another error :

> NameError: name 'attack' is not defined

if *attack* is a string not a variable, you must replace it with "attack" (add quotes)

As @Padraic Cunningham said in comment, *attack* is a variable obviously! so you must define it. :)

Comment: how exactly could q ever be in "attack"?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It couldn't! :)  and so python don't run the code that is in its block! I checked again! It don't run any block! :D

Comment: then the code would never run,  I think it is safe to assume attack is a variable ;)